# bad text alignment with sendmail

Tags: linux, sendmail

I'm trying to send a mail and in the text of the mail put like these:

```
xxxxx     yyyyy    zzzzz
-----     -----    -----
2424      324      23432
I send the email with sendmail but it shows me:
xxxxx     yyyyy    zzzzz
-----     -----      -----
xxxxx     324     23432
```

If I do a cat of the file I see a good alignment. Something could help me please?

The message:

```
Subject: xxxxxx
MIME-version: 1.0
Content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary=_separador_oiqweih3y49yo1_w34rdkq94rhdxqihd_pypqammdlg
--_separador_oiqweih3y49yo1_w34rdkq94rhdxqihd_pypqammdlg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit


ANALISIS INSTANCIA 2

xxxx         yyyy         zzzz                  
------------ ------------ ------------------------------ 
13424        2424234      24234324                        

--_separador_oiqweih3y49yo1_w34rdkq94rhdxqihd_pypqammdlg
Content-type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding: uuencode
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="/tmp/kk"

begin 644 /tmp/ddfjdfd
M#0I!3D%,25-)4R!)3E-404Y#24$@,@T*#0I54U5!4DE/("`@("`@4%)/4$E%
M5$%224\@(%1)4$]?3T)*151/"0D)($Y/34)215]/0DI%5$\)"0D)("`@("`@
M4TE$"2`@("`@4T5224%,#0HM+2TM+2TM+2TM+2T@+2TM+2TM+2TM+2TM("TM
M+2TM+2TM+2TM+2TM+2TM+2TM+2TM+2TM+2TM+2`M+2TM+2TM+2TM+2TM+2TM
M+2TM+2TM+2TM+2TM+2T@+2TM+2TM+2TM+2TM+2TM+2T@+2TM+2TM+2TM+2TM
M+2TM+2T-"D1404)'05(@("`@("!/1%,)("!404),12`)"0D@0U967TI"25]/
L1%-?5$)?1%=?1$%47T9,3U<)"2`@("`@,C@W-`D@("`@("`R-#,P-PT*#0H`
`
end
```

Comment: Can you add which email client you are using to receive the email with? Also please add the specific command you use to send the email.

Comment: Of course. The send mail is:  sendmail -F"xxxx" -f"yyyyy" ${zzz} < ${mail}. I'm trying to view with outlook 2010 client

Comment: Are you using a fixed-width font in Outlook (like Courier)?

Comment: Yes. I change to courier because I have colibri but I have the same problem :-(

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem would be, but in my experience Outlook messes with fixed-width layouts a lot. Would it be possible to view the email in a different email client? At least you would be able to tell if Sendmail is the problem or Outlook.

Comment: above I put the message that I send with sendmail

Comment: Seems like the message is sent OK by sendmail but Outlook is messing with the displayed contents so it's probably best to change your question to why Outlook is displaying the mail differently.

Comment: I send the email to gmail and I see bad alignment also :-(